# Iterative way to go over nested JSON?

Tags: python, json, parsing, recursion, stack

Suppose I have the following Employees JSON file:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "team": [
        {
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Jes",
            "team": []
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "Jek",
            "team": [
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "name": "jane",
                    "team": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "name": "Ron",
                    "team": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to check if id1 has id 2 in his team, the problem is that I do not know the "dept" since each one of the employees can have his own "team" list.

The only solution that I can come up for it is to search the JSON recursively as follows:

```
def find_id(id, data):
    if data['id'] == id:
        return data
    else:
        for emp in data['team']:
            if find_id(id, emp):
                return emp
    return None


def is_bos(id1, id2, data):
    data = find_id(id1, data)
    if data:
        two_found = find_id(id2, data)
        if two_found:
            return True
        return False
    return False
```

For example the following:

```
is_bos(1, 24, data) # should return true
is_bos(1, 32, data) # should return true
is_bos(32, 6, data) # should return false
is_bos(22, 24, data) # should return false
```

And I wonder is there any better way to do this iteratively?

Comment: It would help if you provided complete code and the output, similar to a [mre].

Comment: What's wrong with recursion? This is a recursive data structure, so using recursive programming just makes sense.

Comment: @wjandrea You Right. I have added an example, and the recursive approach has boor space complexity, in the case of a very big and nested JSON file, it will overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always convert recursive functions to iterative functions. Here, an easy technique is to use a stack that you push team members onto as you discover them. It you find the item along the way, return it. If the stack is empty, you're done.

For example:

```
def find(d, target_id):
    stack = d['team'][:]
    while stack:
        item = stack.pop()
        if item['id'] == target_id:
            return item
        stack.extend(item['team'])
    return -1

find(d, 32)
# {'id': 32, 'name': 'jane', 'team': []}

find(d, 100)
-1
```

This essentially creates a depth-first search through your tree. Of course, if you just want a boolean, return that instead of the `item` and `False` at the end.

Comment: Thank you, you are totally right, I should have thought about it, it is basically the same idea to use a stack instead of the function's stack frame.

Comment: @none If you're searching for this kind of information repeatedly on the data tree and you want it to be as fast as possible, it might be worth it to explore using a custom `JSONDecoder` that builds a fully resolved map of "parent" IDs to sets of contained IDs, as it parses the JSON. This way you would not need any loops at all, only direct look-ups.